# A question about rational convex cone

Tags: convex-geometry, polyhedra

Edit: Fix a lattice $N = \mathbb{Z}^n$ and let $N_{\mathbb{R}} = N \otimes \mathbb{R}$.
Let $C(S)$ be a strongly convex rational cone in $N_{\mathbb{R}}$ generated by a finite set $S \subset N$, with following two properties:

- No $v \in S$ is in the interior of $C(S)$.
- $S$ generates $N$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

I have a vector $v \in N$, which has the property:

> $v$ is NOT a nonnegative $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of vectors in $S$.

Does it imply that $v \notin C(S)$? If not, is there any simple low-dimensional counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: lattice is $\mathbb Z^2$, $S = \{(1,0),(1,1),(1,3)\}$, $v=(1,2)$.

Comment: Because of your simple answer, now I recognize that I need to put an additional assumption: What if none of  $v \in S$ is in the interior of $C(S)$?

Comment: Still false: $S=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(1,2,2)\}, v=(1,1,1)$.

Comment: @Lev : you should perhaps add that in each case, there are only finitely many $v$ that are counterexamples.

Comment: Not true: there are could be infinitely many "missing" $v$ near the boundary of the cone.

Comment: Even if the cone is rational ? I would like to see an example.

Comment: Consider $S=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(1,5,0),(1,0,5),(1,5,5)\}$. You will have $(k,5k-1,5k-1)$ missing for all $k$.

Comment: Thank you for this example! It will help correct my misconceptions.